# Как узнать, входит ли point в polygon? android, yandex mapkit

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Задача в следующем, есть какие-то регионы, их нужно обозначить в полигоны (многоугольник) в приложении используя yandex mapKit. Пользователь может ставить точку в любом месте, и в этот момент должно происходить условие, входит ли эта точка в полигон или нет. Вопрос в следующем, возможно ли такое реализовать средствами yandex mapkit? Если нет, может есть альтернативные решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В MapKit не предоставляются инструменты взаимодействия с геометрией.
Это можно сделать в Java. Посмотрите [похожие вопросы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8721406/how-to-determine-if-a-point-is-inside-a-2d-convex-polygon).